uniquness of finite fields if they are inbedded in a algebraic closure
I read in the book of Bosch 3.8 after Theorem 2, that if we fix a algebraic closure of $F_p$ all fields of char p with q elements are equal (not just by isomorphism but really equal). His argument is the following: Let $F_q, F_q'$ be two fields, then we can extend the inclusion $F_p \subset \overset{-}F_p$ to homomorphisms:
$\sigma: F_q \to \overset{-}F_p$ and $\sigma':F_q' \to \overset{-}F_p$. then $\sigma,\sigma'$ restrict by normality to automorphisms of $F_q,F_q'$ i.e $\sigma(F_q) = F_q$ and $\sigma'(F_q')= F_q'$. Now why does it follow that they are equal? I dont understand why this is a proof of our claim.
Moreover I thoguth about the following is it true in general that if we fix a algebraic closure of $K$ as a subfield of the algebraic closure the splittingfield of some polynomials is uniquely determined?

A field with $q$ elements is the set of roots of $x^q-x$.

ok so you want to say that the F_q is the subset of roots in $\overset{-}{K}$ of that polynomial and F_q' is too and so they are equal as the roots are unique inside an algebraic closure? But for this argument we dont need the hole thing with extend the sigma and use normality and so on which is written in the book or am I missing something?
